# pass arguments in call-process as key/value

Tags: shell-command, arguments, call-process

I try to run a command which takes some arguments and requires to pass some attributes to the API.
I understand that call-process takes args as strings but any invocation complains about
`wrong-type-argument listp`

```
(wrong-type-argument listp "'TEST=hpc_powerman'")
```

> (apply #'call-process "/usr/bin/openqa-cli" nil "*mybuf*" nil "api" "--osd"
> "-X" "post" "isos"
> "'ISO=SLE-15-SP6-Online-aarch64-Build40.1-Media1.iso'"
> "'DISTRI=sle'"
> "'VERSION=15-SP6'"
> "'FLAVOR=Online'"
> "'ARCH=aarch64'"
> "'_NOOBSOLETEBUILD=1'"
> "'BUILD=40.1'"
> "'_GROUP_ID=130'"
> "'TEST=hpc_powerman'")

How it looks on terminal

```
400 Bad Request
Error: missing parameters: DISTRI VERSION FLAVOR ARCH
❯ echo $?
1
❯ openqa-cli api --pretty --host https://openqa.suse.de -X POST isos ISO=SLE-15-SP6-Online-aarch64-Build40.1-Media1.iso DISTRI=sle VERSION=15-SP6 FLAVOR=Online ARCH=aarch64 _NOOBSOLETEBUILD=1 BUILD=40.1 _GROUP_ID=130 TEST=hpc_powerman
{
   "count" : 2,
   "failed" : [],
   "ids" : [
      12931264,
      12931265
   ],
   "scheduled_product_id" : 2004035
}
```

I tried to escape the `=` but it doesnt make any difference.
Another attempt was to send the last part as one string.

Any ideas how can i make this work?

Answer (score 3):

The last argument to `apply` must be a list, see the documentation (emphasis mine)

> Call FUNCTION with our remaining args, **using our last arg as list of args**.

You can group all arguments passed to the command in a quoted list, this has the (IMHO) nice side effect to show they are all related and distinct from the other arguments of `call-process`

```lisp
(apply #'call-process "/usr/bin/openqa-cli" nil "mybuf" nil
       '("api" "--osd" "-X" "post" "isos"
         "'ISO=SLE-15-SP6-Online-aarch64-Build40.1-Media1.iso'"
         "'DISTRI=sle'"
         "'VERSION=15-SP6'"
         "'FLAVOR=Online'"
         "'ARCH=aarch64'"
         "'_NOOBSOLETEBUILD=1'"
         "'BUILD=40.1'"
         "'_GROUP_ID=130'"
         "'TEST=hpc_powerman'"))
```

There is an even simpler solution, unless your real code is more complex and really need `apply` you can get rid of it and use `call-process` directly

```lisp
(call-process "/usr/bin/openqa-cli" nil "mybuf" nil
              "api" "--osd" "-X" "post" "isos"
              "'ISO=SLE-15-SP6-Online-aarch64-Build40.1-Media1.iso'"
              "'DISTRI=sle'"
              "'VERSION=15-SP6'"
              "'FLAVOR=Online'"
              "'ARCH=aarch64'"
              "'_NOOBSOLETEBUILD=1'"
              "'BUILD=40.1'"
              "'_GROUP_ID=130'"
              "'TEST=hpc_powerman'")
```